# Python 3- syslog.syslog works but logging.handlers.sysloghandler logs nothing

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, syslog

I have a number of scripts that use `logging.error(msg)` style logging messages.

I originally had these handled by a `FileHandler` but now I need to change it over to a `SysLogHandler`.  I can't get the `SysLogHandler` to work, by which I mean there are no exceptions but nothing ends up in the logs.

On the other hand, I can get messages logged through `syslog.syslog` with this code:

```
import syslog
syslog.openlog(ident="LOG_IDENTIFIER", logoption=syslog.LOG_PID, facility=syslog.LOG_LOCAL3)
syslog.syslog('syslog test msg local3')
```

and this is what I'm using for the `sysloghandler`:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
logger = logging.getLogger('myLogger')
handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address='/dev/log',facility=19)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logging.error('sysloghandler test msg local3')
```

`facility=19` because that's the value for `SysLogHandler.LOG_LOCAL`.

I'm thinking the issue is the `address` setting. The log files are located in `/var/log` but that doesn't seem to work. I've tried not specifying an address (so it defaults to `localhost` port 514) still nothing gets logged.

I need to know either how I can determine the correct address info or how to troubleshoot the issue if that isn't the problem.

Comment: Are you sure the syslog server is configured to listen on a Unix domain socket (`/dev/log`)? Sometimes they're set up to listen on UDP only.Also, the default UDP port is 514, not 516.

Comment: sorry wrote the port from memory, you're correct.  Is there a definitive way to check whether it uses a domain socket or a UDP port?  I did not have a hand in setting up the syslog.

Comment: It is unlikely to find a system that has syslog listening on a network socket but not on `/dev/log`.  A quick test is to see if `/dev/log` exists, if so, you're probably in good shape.  Your code as written works just fine on my system.  Make sure your syslog configuration isn't doing something special with messages at the given facility.  Consider using named constants from the `syslog` module (like `syslog.LOCAL3`) instead of magic numbers.  Try a common facility like `LOG_DAEMON` and see if that shows up instead.

Comment: There is not a /dev/log directory.  The actual log files are in /var/log but that apparently is not a domain socket as address='/var/log' does not work in the SysLogHandler initiation.  It results in ConnectionRefusedErrors.  Is there anyway to determine what domain sockets exist on a system?  Tried LOG_DAEMON but still no logs.

Comment: You should probably take a look at the configuration of your syslog daemon and see from where it is collecting logs.

Comment: Can you suggest how to do this?  Again I had no part in setting up this syslogging.  I can see an rsyslog process running but I honestly don't know if that is being used or syslogd(8).  And in either case I'm not sure how to check what you are suggesting.  If it is using rsyslog would that be in the rsyslog.conf?  I have looked at that several times.

Comment: Having the exact same issue on RHEL 8 but my /dev/log exists and using `logger test` works perfectly fine as well. When turning on logging exceptions I get OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor from handlers.py Would love you fix this as I prefer the logging handler to syslog.